# January 2019 Photo competition

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

Over the three months December 2018 - February 2019 I want to run a photo competition, (it can run longer if well accepted and active, but three months is guaranteed.)
The highest voted answer will get the fame and bragging rights. An extra virtual prize may be given to that or any other photo.

The basic rules are the same as those for the last competition. Only from now on the 'user who has taken the photo' can be one person or two working together, like a husband and wife or two people who travel(ed) together.

Rules:

- 1 photo per answer.
- May submit more than 1 answer per user.
- try and keep it non offensive.
- All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and the date the photo was taken.
- the photo has to be taken by the user* who posted it and taken in the time frame given in the description for that month's photo.
  (*Or one of a two people team, give credit to the actual person who took the photo.)

The next rules changes per month, the subject of the picture and its 'when it was taken'.

For the month of January I would like to set the rule:

- The photo is of nature.
  Buildings, roads, and other man made objects may be present in the picture but should have a minor role in the subject and composition.
- The photo can have been taken between the announcement of this competition (11-11-2018) and the last day of January 2019.
- The photo should not include people as important part of the picture. If unavoidable, people can be included as long as they are not recognizable.
- Remember we are 'Travel' stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)
- No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of January 2019, voting will run till midnight, the end of 31st of January 2019 and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

Update after the end of the month.
The highest voted photo did not meet all the rules, so the second highest wins this month.
Congratulations mts, the bragging rights are yours.

The virtual prize this month is for Sue. You get an afternoon of bird and small mammal watching in your nearest park, travel and binoculars not included. And no refund if it rains.

Comment: Hi Willeke! The rules are very clear, so I don't want to be a pest asking for a change, but I guess I am! Might you consider expanding the date the picture had to be taken? I'm in the United States, and we don't get out a lot or travel in the winter. I'd have more to offer if we could go back farther. My photos wouldn't be better than the gorgeous things you have and will get, I'd just be more able to participate! Meanwhile, I'm looking for something we took during the required time that people might like!

Comment: @Sue, you can take a photo out of your window (have your other half take one) and post that. But it is a fun competition and we mostly want people to send in photos they like. So post and be open about the date you took it. Voters will weigh quality against date when they do vote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Coral (?) structure at the Great Barrier Reef. Picture taken at Flynn's Reef off Cairns on 6 December 2018 by me. The picture has been modified to reduce file size.

Comment: Congratulations, the bragging rights your yours, mts.

Comment: Congratulations mts! I love coral, what a gorgeous animal!

Answer (score 13):

[image]
One of many lagoons in Lençóis Maranhenses National Park, Brazil, taken August 2018.

Comment: Can you please add the date this photo was taken? (It is part of the rules for this month.)

Comment: @Willeke my bad. I took it in August 2018, I didn't read the rules properly. Should I just remove it? Or leave it just for the record, not participating in the contest?

Comment: I have edited the date in for you. Leave it, people like the photo. Just realize that you will not win this month.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

The very last of Fall in Atlanta, taken on 22 November 2018.

Comment: Very nice colors!

Answer (score 10):

Crossing the Essequibo, in Guyana, at sunrise. December 2018.

[image: Essequibo crossing]

Answer (score 8):

[image: DSC00554-1]

**Reflections at Yuanmingyuan Park**
Old Summer Palace. Beijing. China.

Comment: Can you please add the date this photo was taken? (It is part of the rules for this month.)

Answer (score 7):

Echidna, taken at North Head near Manly, Sydney. Taken (amazingly) on the 11/11.

[image: echidna]

Comment: Echidnas are awesome and so fascinating! I'm jealous you got to see one up close!

Comment: @Sue second once I've sen up close, first adult one! Was also lucky to see a platypus a couple of years back near Canberra, that was a highlight for me.  Wombats are probably my favourite tho.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Fall]

Advent of Fall in Virginia USA - Late October 2018

Answer (score 4):

[image: Lone winter tree up the hill.]
Lone winter tree, Calne Wiltshire UK, photo graph taken by Willeke 26-12-2018, while traveling in England.
(Photo is free for all to use.)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Copse in the woods behind Wilsontown Ironworks, Lanark. Taken 1/1/2019 by me during a post-Hogmanay walk in the brisk new year air.

Answer (score 4):

This photo is looking up at Blackwood trees on the walk to Hogarth Falls, Strahan Tasmania Australia.  The photo was taken during a misty afternoon on 4th of January this year.[image: Personal photo from holidays in January]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tail of squirrel as he's jumping down into the bush after I scared him!]

I scared a squirrel who was standing on the bush outside my house. This is a picture of his tail as he jumped down into the bush to get away!

I took it myself on December 21, 2018.

Comment: The virtual prize this month is for Sue. You get an afternoon of bird and small mammal watching in your nearest park, travel and binoculars not included. And no refund if it rains.

Comment: Willeke, you are so wonderful!!! Thanks for this! I'm so looking forward to my "gift." I'll use it wisely and with tons of fun!

Answer (score 4):

[image: Leven Canyon, Tasmania Australia, taken by me 28 December 2018]

View from the lookout at Leven Canyon, Tasmania Australia, taken by me on 28 December 2018.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Faisal Mosque Grounds. Islamabad, Pakistan - 19 January 2019

Answer (score 3):

[image: Mountain range as seen from Kunyang Rest Stop, Taiwan, elev. 3000m+]

Mountain range as seen from Kunyang Rest Stop, near the boundary of Taroko National Park in Taiwan. Elevation 3000m+, cloud base height on the day the photo is taken (early Jan 2019) around the area is ~3100-3200m.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Double rainbow. Taken Dec 2, 2018 in Wheatfield Township, Michigan, USA.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

A view of the Murree Hill Station as seen during a trip to Pakistan. This is a famous tourist destination there. If you zoom in you will see that the snow covered peak actually has hundreds of homes, hotels and other buildings hidden beneath the snow.

Picture taken on 26th January 2019 on N75 Murree Islamabad Expressway.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Wind Turbines]

Wind Turbines in Netherlands - November 2018